# text in textbox if in datagrid selection change is null

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

How can I get the command to return empty space, if I have in the database a NULL id and other space???

[image]

Comment: Is it `row`, `row,Cells` or `row.Cells[18]` that is `null`?

Comment: Why you converting to `int` if you want empty space?

Comment: row.Cells[18] that is null

Comment: Your line `if (cotaID != null)` isn't required. An `int` cannot be `null`.

Comment: Are you sure that `row.Cells[18]` is `null`? I think if Cell at index = 18 doesn't exist, then `IndexOutOfRange` exception will be thrown. Maybe `row.Cells[18].Value` is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need check if `row.Cells[18]` is null.

Use [inline Operator ?:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
var cotaID = (row.Cells[18] == null) ? 0 : (int)row.Cells[18].Value;
```

This "inline if statement" equal to

```
if(row.Cells[18] == null)
    cotaID = 0;
else
    cotaID = (int)row.Cells[18].Value;
```

Comment: no i don't use this operator because i know nothing about it "?:"

Comment: Operator `?:` is just shorter method to write `if .. else ..` statement

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you work with `DataGridView`, you should use the ContentClick event and use the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs e`.
Then you can check the input with:

```
 if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1)
 {
     return;
 }
```

and perform whatever actions you need.